# Php curl doesn't get jquery cookie?

Tags: php, jquery, cookies, get, php-curl

I'm trying to get a cookie from [this page](https://vtcgame.vn/nap-vcoin/qua-the-cao.html). If you load that page, you will notice that the first time you will receive an incomplete cookie. But if refresh the page, you will receive a full cookie. I have tried with curloptions *CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR* & *CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE*.
How can I get full cookie with curl() in PHP?

Comment: If it's set via jQuery then you can't get it via PHP-cURL because PHP-cURL is a server-side script and jQuery runs on a user's browser.

Comment: Thank for answer ! How can i get that cookie?